# Regarding Memcached source code running issue

Tags: memcached, libmemcached

using the following link,tried running the memcached source code...

```
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model
```

while running it,configure command works properly.

when i'm running the make command,it throws the following error....How to solve this issue?

syscon@syscon-OptiPlex-3020:~/Documents/work/memcached-1.4.5$ sudo make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/syscon/Documents/work/memcached-1.4.5'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/syscon/Documents/work/memcached-1.4.5/doc'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/syscon/Documents/work/memcached-1.4.5/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for`all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/syscon/Documents/work/memcached-1.4.5/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/syscon/Documents/work/memcached-1.4.5/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/syscon/Documents/work/memcached-1.4.5'
gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-memcached.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-memcached.Tpo -c -o memcached-memcached.o`test -f 'memcached.c' || echo './'`memcached.c
memcached.c: In function ‘complete_incr_bin’:
memcached.c:1023:16: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
                c->binary_header.request.cas == ITEM_get_cas(it))) {
                ^
memcached.c:1044:13: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
             c->cas = ITEM_get_cas(it);
             ^
memcached.c:1061:17: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
                 c->cas = ITEM_get_cas(it);
                 ^
memcached.c: In function ‘process_bin_get’:
memcached.c:1193:9: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
         rsp->message.header.response.cas = htonll(ITEM_get_cas(it));
         ^
memcached.c: In function ‘process_bin_update’:
memcached.c:1889:5: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
     ITEM_set_cas(it, c->binary_header.request.cas);
     ^
memcached.c:1905:5: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
     if (ITEM_get_cas(it) != 0) {
     ^
memcached.c: In function ‘process_bin_append_prepend’:
memcached.c:1949:5: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
     ITEM_set_cas(it, c->binary_header.request.cas);
     ^
memcached.c: In function ‘process_bin_delete’:
memcached.c:2014:9: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
         if (cas == 0 || cas == ITEM_get_cas(it)) {
         ^
memcached.c: In function ‘do_store_item’:
memcached.c:2127:9: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
         else if (ITEM_get_cas(it) == ITEM_get_cas(old_it)) {
         ^
memcached.c:2127:9: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
memcached.c:2144:25: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
                         (unsigned long long)ITEM_get_cas(old_it),
                         ^
memcached.c:2145:25: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
                         (unsigned long long)ITEM_get_cas(it));
                         ^
memcached.c:2158:13: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
             if (ITEM_get_cas(it) != 0) {
             ^
memcached.c:2160:17: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
                 if (ITEM_get_cas(it) != ITEM_get_cas(old_it)) {
                 ^
memcached.c:2160:17: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
memcached.c:2202:13: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
             c->cas = ITEM_get_cas(it);
             ^
memcached.c:2214:9: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
         c->cas = ITEM_get_cas(it);
         ^
memcached.c: In function ‘process_get_command’:
memcached.c:2592:45: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
                                             (unsigned long long)ITEM_get_cas(it));
                                             ^
memcached.c: In function ‘process_update_command’:
memcached.c:2751:5: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
     ITEM_set_cas(it, req_cas_id);
     ^
memcached.c: In function ‘do_add_delta’:
memcached.c:2870:9: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
         ITEM_set_cas(it, (settings.use_cas) ? get_cas_id() : 0);
         ^
memcached.c: In function ‘main’:
memcached.c:4630:13: error: variable ‘udp_port’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
         int udp_port;
             ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [memcached-memcached.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/syscon/Documents/work/memcached-1.4.5'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/syscon/Documents/work/memcached-1.4.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 1):

cd memcached-1.4.5/

wget http://johntech-resource.googlecode.com/files/fix-strict-aliasing.patch

patch memcached.h fix-strict-aliasing.patch

./configure

nano Makefile # add -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable to CFLAGS.

make

make install

it helped  for me. 
Taken from
http://www.cnblogs.com/balaamwe/archive/2012/05/31/2528066.html